# Sending an e-mail in python containing an e-mail every hour only if there is a change in that table

Tags: python

I have a program which loops through every hour and sends an e-mail with the results. However, the table may be blank at the start of the day and also there may be no changes in the table each hour. Here is my code for sending the e-mail and the table (all pretty straight forward I think)

```
table = df.loc[:, ['colm1', 'colm2', 'colm3']]
body = '<html><body>' + table.to_html() + '</body></html>'


outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'xxx@yyy.com'
mail.Subject = 'Report'
mail.HTMLBody = body
mail.Send()
```

What I want is for it to only send an e-mail if the table is not blank or if the table differs from the last hour. Would love some suggestions!

Comment: Just clear the table once you are done with it? Who updates the table? How do you load its data?

Comment: What have you tried to add this feature so far?

Comment: Depending on the size of the table, just compare the output of `table.to_html()` to the value of the previous iteration.

Comment: look into Caching with Python, An ideal way for comparing would be to add a version or a Last Updated token in your table which can further be stored in your cache, compare those two and take actions accordingly. This way you will prevent the hassle of comparing entire body of the table if and when it becomes too large. This link might help you start with cache [Into to Cache](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/02/25/python-an-intro-to-caching/)